# RouteProvider resolve AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code :
Js:

```
angular.module('main', [])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.when('/tables/bricks', {
              controller: "myController",
              resolve: {
                  "check" : function($location){
                      if(!$scope.bricks) {
                           $route.reload();
                      }
                  }
              },
            templateUrl: 'tables/bricks.html'
        });

         $routeProvider.otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/tables/datatables'
        });

    }
])


.controller('myController', function($scope, $location, $http) {
    var vm = this;

     $scope.Bricks = function(){
        $location.path('/tables/bricks');
    };

    vm.getbricks = function(n){
        var url = n;
        $http({
            method: 'GET' ,
            url: url,
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.bricks = data.data;
                console.log($scope.bricks);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });

    };
});
```

HTML:

```
 <button ng-click="vm.getbricks(n.bricks_url);Bricks();"></button>
```

After click the button in html, my page goes into `/tables/bricks`, but nothing happend, because `resolve` probably is wrong. What I want - that i could go to `/tables/bricks` only then, when `$scope.bricks` exist, so only when `vm.bricks()` will be called.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `vm.getbricks` will always return something (in success or error handler), so will never be falsy, and you will always call the `Bricks()` constructor. try to return `true` on success callback and `false` in error callback.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` is for controllers, which it can't reach in the config. Instead, you should be returning something from a service, which will be called during your *resolve*. E.g. `if(YourService.getbricks())`

**Solution**: move your logic from a controller into a service. And make sure to `return` a value from it that can be checked in the config.

```js
app.service('BrickService', function() {
  this.getbricks = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url)        // return the Promise
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;    // return the data
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
});
```

With this you can inject the service into the config and run its function.

```js
angular.module('main', [])
  .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/tables/bricks', {
        controller: "myController",
        resolve: {
          "check": function(BrickService) {    // inject
            if ( BrickService.getbricks() ) {  // run its function
              $route.reload();
            }
          }
        },
        templateUrl: 'tables/bricks.html'
      });

      $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/tables/datatables'
      });
    }
  ])
```

You can also use the loaded values **in the controller** after they have been resolved. For that, you would need to simply return it. So change the logic to this:

```
resolve: {
  "check": function(BrickService) {    // inject
    var bricks = BrickService.getbricks(); // run its function
    if ( bricks ) {  
       $route.reload();
    }
    return bricks; // return the result (note: it's not a Promise anymore)
  }
}
```

Then you can **inject** this resolve into your controller:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $location, $http, check) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.bricks = check;
  ...
```

(Note `check` was added)

Comment: But how i call this service from HTML?

Comment: @bafix2203 you can't. Controllers are responsible for your view. So render data and call functions there. But even if you call a controller's function, it can execute the service methods. E.g. `$scope.foo = function(){ YourService.bar() }`, where `foo()` is called with `ng-click` or something else